# Session variables not clearing after Session.Clear() and Session.Abandon() in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, session-variables

After running penetration tests on our site, our IT Security pointed out that session id's on our server doesn't get cleared out after the users log out.

our code to clear the session is as follows:

```
Session.Clear()
Session.RemoveAll()
Session.Abandon()

Dim Cookie1 As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "")
Cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
Response.Cookies.Add(Cookie1)

Dim Cookie2 As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "")
Cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
Response.Cookies.Add(Cookie2)

FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
```

We confirmed this by having UserA log in and forging cookies based on that login. After UserA logs out, we log in UserB and as expected, we acquired all the session values stored in UserA's sessionID.

Is there any other way to clear the session data?

Comment: have you tried signing out before you clear and abandon the session ? The session will continue to exist until your request is done. so if signout sets something in the session it might be activated again?

Comment: yes. I've already tried putting formsauthentication.signout before clearing session

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.removeall(v=vs.110).aspx), `Session.Clear` and `Session.RemoveAll` do the same thing.  You need to call this before you call `Clear`:

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
```

Comment: Hi joehanna,

I've already tried that option already, and sadly it didn't work.

Comment: How are your security guys determining the session IDs are still active?

Comment: they hired a company to do penetration testing on the website and the result showed that the sessionIDs are still active after users sign out

Comment: But this isn't necessarily a bad thing.  Just because you logged out, it doesn't mean the IIS session is dead.  You have taken all the steps to clear out `Session State`, meaning any identifiable information for a session has been destroyed. What is left is the Worker Process only (no data), ready for you to potentially log back in etc.  It will timeout and drop off. Once you have cleared the session state, the fact that the worker process is still running until it times out does not pose a security risk.  If they believe it does, get them to explain HOW this is so.

Comment: Well the problem is that the session state that is related to the SessionID doesn't actually get cleared. As I stated, we confirmed this by simulating a session fixation by forging the cookies from UserA's login then logging him. After that, UserB logs in and we inject the SessionID from UserA and we acquire UserA's session variables

Comment: Actually this is a very big security risk, knowing that session cookies doesn't need formsauthentication to work

Comment: do you set the cookie form the server or from the client? there is actually not that easy to fake a session id if you don't already (as you do) know it.

Comment: the cookie is issued by ASP server side. the problem is that data saved on session still exists after session.clear and session.abandon meaning that if an attacker hijacks the session, it will be available even if the victim logs out.

Comment: note that we signed out UserA before injecting his cookies to the other users and still his session data shows up which is alarming

Comment: Can you check to see if `Session_End` is being fired when you execute `Session.Abandon`?

Comment: funny thing is that Session_End is firing. as a temporary fix, i manually null out the values of all session variables when the user clicks the signout button and add validation on the login page_load

Comment: In the article, it gave code for Login.aspx to destroy session state objects and cookies.  Did you try that?

Comment: Wasn't your code in your Logout page?  The sample has it in the Login page after you have redirected.  It would be worth trying it exactly as shown.

Comment: yes, the link you gave us has similar pattern like ours. 
`Session.Abandon()` and
`Response.Cookie.Add(New HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""))` is in our code too

Comment: @JohnMichaelTolentino, if you found a work-around, would you mind posting it as an answer here?  You stated that nulling out session values worked for you - but we have not been successful with that, either.

Comment: I'm by no means a security expert, but to respond to joehanna's question of how this is a security risk... I'll give it a shot based on what we are demonstrating.  We are simulating a man-in-the-middle attack.  Once the user is logged in, we are able to get their session id.  Even after they log out, call abandon, clear out the session values, etc... it doesn't matter.  We are able to use that session ID to effectively stay logged in, indefinitely. All we have to do is hit a page every 5 minutes or so to keep the session active and we can stay logged in as long as we'd like. Huge security risk

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this comprehensive page from the Microsoft Support site.  It deals explicitly with what you are trying to do.  It has a very good explanation on the how sessions can remain in tact etc.

It uses logic in the Login.aspx page to destroy sessions and cookies to overcome spoofing.

Note: the example is in c# but can be easily converted to VB.  Let me know if you need help with that.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899918

Comment: thanks for the link, will look into this and let you know the result

Comment: I've read this article, and it does not explicitly give an example of what the OP is trying to accomplish.  In fact, it seems to say the opposite - that the session will remain open even after logging off, so that the session can be re-used across sub domains: "...the user will not lose their session state after the Abandon method is called from one application"